# How to make a page transition animation like tinder when the user want to see the detail of the Candidate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image: How to make this kind of page transition in flutter?]

I was trying to make a tinder clone for my own personal project, and I found out that tinder has so many animation that looks interactive, especially when the user wants to detail of the candidate profile. How to make this kind of animation page transition(like the gif that I gave)?

Comment: Use a Hero Widget that should do the trick. For the download button you'll need an AnimationController.

Comment: @ArshShaikh alright thanks mann